A functor $\mathsf{Grp} \to \mathsf{Grp}$ with $\mathbb{Z} \mapsto G$
Given a group $G$, does there exist a functor $\square \tilde{\otimes} G: \mathsf{Grp} \to \mathsf{Grp}$ with the following properties?

$\mathbb{Z} \tilde{\otimes} G \cong G$

$\square \tilde{\otimes} G$ preserves all direct sums, direct products and free products


The idea is that $\square \tilde{\otimes} G$ is a "base change from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $G$". I'm particularly interested in the cases $G = \mathbb{Q}$ and $G = \mathbb{R}$.

What have you tried? Why has it not worked? What are the "obvious" guesses and why don't they work? Is there any reason you want to find a functor that satisfies these specific properties? It feels a bit random.

@JonathanBeardsley It's definitely not random, and I think this question is already interesting enough to not have additional context. (+1)

My point is that I can I think of several things that might work but it seems like a waste of effort if we have no clue what the OP originally asked.

This feels unlikely. For example, one easily verifies that $\mathbb{F}n \mathbin{\tilde{\otimes}} G = G^{\ast n}$ for all $1 \leq n \leq \infty$. But while $\mathbb{F}\infty \hookrightarrow \mathbb{F}_2$, it is not true that $G^{\ast \infty} \hookrightarrow G \ast G$ for all $G$. (Say, $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.) While this doesn’t directly prove such functors cannot exist, it does make it unlikely, in my opinion.

Here is an idea for how to define such a functor: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4907258/the-pushout-requireamscd-begincd-mathbbz-ast-h-alpha-ast-h-g
