The pushout $F_\alpha(H)$ of $H \overset{\pi}{\longleftarrow} \mathbb{Z}^{\ast H} \overset{\alpha^{\ast H}}{\longrightarrow} G^{\ast H}$
$\require{AMScd}$
Definition 1:
If $G$ is a group and $X$ is a set, define $G^{\ast X} = \ast_{x \in X} G$. This is functorial in both $G$ and $X$:
If $G$ and $H$ are groups, $\varphi: G \to H$ is a group homomorphism and $X$ is a set, we have a group homomorphism $\varphi^{\ast X}: G^{\ast X} \to H^{\ast X}$ that acts via $\varphi$ on each free factor.
If $G$ is a group, $X$ and $Y$ are sets and $f: X \to Y$ is a set mapping, we have a group homomorphism $G^{\ast f}: G^{\ast X} \to G^{\ast X}$ that sends the $x$-th free factor to the $f(x)$-th free factor.
If $G$ and $H$ are groups, $\varphi: G \to H$ is a group homomorphism, $X$ and $Y$ are sets and $f: X \to Y$ is a set mapping, we have the following commutative diagram:
$$
\begin{CD}
G^{\ast X} @>G^{\ast f}>> G^{\ast Y}\\
@V \varphi^{\ast X} V V @VV \varphi^{\ast Y} V\\
H^{\ast X} @>>H^{\ast f}> H^{\ast Y}
\end{CD}
$$
Definition 2:
If $G$ is a group, define $\pi: \mathbb{Z}^{\ast G} \to G$ to be the group homomorphism that sends the $g$-th free generator to $g$.
If $G$ and $H$ are groups and $\varphi: G \to H$ is a group homomorphism, we have the following commutative diagram:
$$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z}^{\ast G} @>\mathbb{Z}^{\ast \varphi}>> \mathbb{Z}^{\ast H}\\
@V \pi_G V V @VV \pi_H V\\
G @>>\varphi> H
\end{CD}
$$
Definition 3:
Let $G$ be a group and $\alpha: \mathbb{Z} \to G$ be a group homomorphism. Define a functor $F_\alpha: \mathsf{Grp} \to \mathsf{Grp}$ in the following way:
Given a group $H$, define $F_\alpha(H)$ to be the pushout of the following diagram:
$$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z}^{\ast H} @>\alpha^{\ast H}>> G^{\ast H}\\
@V \pi V V\\
H
\end{CD}
$$
This means that we obtain the following commutative diagram:
$$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z}^{\ast H} @>\alpha^{\ast H}>> G^{\ast H}\\
@V \pi V V @VV \beta V\\
H @>>\gamma> F_\alpha(H)
\end{CD}
$$
Given two groups $H_1$ and $H_2$ and a group homomorphism $\varphi: H_1 \to H_2$, consider the cube diagram that consists of the diagrams for $F_\alpha(H_1)$ and $F_\alpha(H_2)$ as well as the maps $\varphi$, $\mathbb{Z}^{\ast \varphi}$ and $G^{\ast \varphi}$:

In this diagram, the front and back squares are commutative as $F_\alpha(H_1)$ and $F_\alpha(H_2)$ are by definition the pushouts of the upper left parts. The top square is commutative by the previous observation from definition 1. The left square is commutative by the previous observation from definition 2.
Now, consider the maps $\gamma_2 \circ \varphi: H_1 \to F_\alpha(H_2)$ and $\beta_2 \circ G^{\ast \varphi}: G^{\ast H_1} \to F_\alpha(H_2)$. We have $\beta_2 \circ G^{\ast \varphi} \circ \alpha^{\ast H_1} = \beta_2 \circ \alpha^{\ast H_2} \circ \mathbb{Z}^{\ast \varphi} = \gamma_2 \circ \pi_2 \circ \mathbb{Z}^{\ast \varphi} = \gamma_2 \circ \varphi \circ \pi_1$. Hence, since $F_\alpha(H_1)$ is the pushout of $\mathbb{Z}^{\ast H_1}$ along $\alpha^{\ast H_1}$ and $\pi_1$, we have a unique map, which we will call $F_\alpha(\varphi): F_\alpha(H_1) \to F_\alpha(H_2)$, with $\gamma_2 \circ \varphi = F_\alpha(\varphi) \circ \gamma_1$ and $\beta_2 \circ G^{\ast \varphi} = F_\alpha(\varphi) \circ \beta_1$. Hence we obtain the following commutative cube diagram:

It can be shown that $F_\alpha$ is indeed a functor. Additionally, from the commutative cube diagram above, it is clear that there is a natural transformation $\operatorname{id}_\mathsf{Grp} \Rightarrow F_\alpha$.
The question
Does the functor $F_\alpha$ have a common name? Where can I read more about this functor? Can you give any reference?
Does the functor $F_\alpha$ preserve limits? Does $F_\alpha$ preserve colimits?
The idea is that $F_\alpha$ is a "base change from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $G$ along $\alpha$". (See A functor $\mathsf{Grp} \to \mathsf{Grp}$ with $\mathbb{Z} \mapsto G$)

Unrelated, but I just learned about the AMScd package from this post. I've been making all of my commutative diagrams in Tikz this whole time!

@CameronWilliams Well, Tikz is far better. But only AMScd works on Math Overflow.

Please avoid such large formulas in subject lines. They mess up the display of questions lists in many instances.

@ArturoMagidin I've changed the title to not use a commutative diagram anymore.

Thanks.${}{}{}{}$

A couple of notes: the map $\pi$ Is the counit of the adjunction between the underlying set functor and the free group functor, evaluated at $H$; that is, $\varepsilon\colon \mathsf{F}(\mathsf{U}(H))\to H$, where $\mathsf{U}(H)$ is the underlying set of $H$< and $\mathsf{F}$ is the free group functor. (Since $\mathbb{Z}^{*H}$ is the free group on $\mathsf{U}(H)$.) The fact that it comes form a natural transformation should give a lot of a the functorial properties "for free".

The map $\alpha$ is equivalent to choosing a $g\in G$; then you are taking the coproduct of $\mathsf{U}(H)$ copies of $G$, and finally it looks to me that you are taking the quotient of this group modulo identifying $g_{h_1}g_{h_2}$ with $g_{h_1h_2}$.
